# Prediction market based on LMSR: Sell, or buy other side?

Tags: markets, theory

Consider a [prediction market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_market) with two outcomes (Yes and No) and a scoring rule based on [Hansons’s LMSR](http://hanson.gmu.edu/mktscore.pdf), i.e. *ln(e<sup>a</sup>+e<sup>b</sup>)*, where *a* and *b* are the number of Yes resp. No shares sold.

Assume that I have previously bought 10 Yes shares, but now I changed my mind and want to bet on the other side. I have the option to either sell my 10 yes shares, or buy 10 no shares.

When should I choose one or the other option? Is it always the same, or does it depend on, say, the current market?

Answer (score 3):

For the market it does not matter, the prices/chances change exactly the same:
*e<sup>a-10</sup>/(e<sup>a-10</sup>+e<sup>b</sup>)* = *e<sup>a</sup>/(e<sup>a</sup>+e<sup>b+10</sup>)*.

For you as the trader, selling 10 yes shares is preferable. It means you get your money out and can invest it elsewhere.